# ios compare two NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

I got confuse how to compare two NSMutableArray.Here are my code. If the array element already exists in the local it will take it else take the default array. How to do it ?

```
   for (NSDictionary *data in array) {
                    NSString *fbid = [data objectForKey:@"id"];

                    for (KP_PERSON *person in self.myPersonArray) {
                        if ([person.UserDef2 isEqualToString:fbid]) {
                            //Found fbid take the array element
                        }
                        else{
                            //continue take the array
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Please help. Thanks.

I am trying to compare the local database with json Array. if the fbid already exists in the  local database, it will add to the object else it will use the json array to populate the data to tableview.

Comment: Maybe it's just me... what exactly are you trying to compare and where are you trying to consume it? Do you mind giving an example to help drive a solution?

Comment: But where is the code for comparing two arrays. The code you posted is comparing two NSStrings, rt?

Comment: Sorry my mistake,it is comparing to the NSString

Answer (score 0):

Jason, I am not pretty sure about what your requirements are but as per I understand predicate is answer for your question, which are very helpful for searching. Block predicates have made it very easy to use.

```
NSArray *allFbIds = [self.myPersonArray valueForKeyPath:@"UserDef2"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    NSDictionary *data = (NSDictionary *)evaluatedObject;
    NSString *fbid = [data objectForKey:@"id"];
    return [allFbIds containsObject:fbid];
}];

NSArray *filetr = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

If any of fbID will be available in property UserDef2 in KP_PERSON object of myPersonArray that will be in the filtered in the array.

I think this might solve your problem.